# Request for MageStackDay IV: Tag Cleanup

Tags: discussion, tags, magestackday

### Hi, it's me, the [tag janitor](https://magento.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms).

As the next MageStackDay is coming, I'd love to see a new section next to voting, answering and closing: tag cleanup.

IMHO the site has a problem with overspecific and redundant tags, so it's hard to find the "right" tags for a question and also hard to find questions to answer by tag (without following hundreds of useless tags).

So my proposal is to hunt down overspecific tags and create synonyms:

[image: screenshot of synonyms suggestions]

This way, these tags are still in the system and if somebody wants to use them, they automatically get changed to the master tag of the synonym.

#### What's overly specific?

The number of questions per tag is a good indicator, but should not be the only criterion because with Magento 2, new relevant tags are coming. Also some tags don't get many questions (ex. [testing](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/testing), 39 questions) but are still relevant and generic.

But tags that are in the system for several months and still only have a few questions **and 0 followers** are probably too specific.

Ask yourself: Would anybody consider themselves **an expert in X** and follow/fav the tag? Or is there a more generic tag where it fits in?

#### Too generic tags

Then there are other tags with many questions which are totally useless, because they are *too* generic, thus meaningless (ex. [custom](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/custom), 263 questions).

Same question: Would anybody consider themselves an expert in "custom"? Unfortunately, those cannot be solved with synonyms and need to be [burninated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate/239191#239191), i.e. removed from the questions. It's common in other SE sites like StackOverflow but not yet on this one, but I hope, MageStackDay is a good chance to start.

#### Would anybody join me on this mission?

Critic and suggestions are welcome!

*A little motivation: As a reward for accepted synonyms in your own tags, [tag badges](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/badges?tab=Tags&filter=all) are waiting ;-)*

Comment: ha ha `A little motivation: ` is very good

Answer (score 5):

Thanks a lot for bringing this up, Fabian!

We've included it in the Todo-List of the announcement of the upcoming MageStackDay: [Register now for MageStackDay IV on January 15th & 16th 2016](https://magento.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/794/register-now-for-magestackday-iv-on-january-15th-16th-2016)

Answer (score 1):

Nice initiative Fabian!

I'll join you. Although I haven't got enough rep in almost all of the tags to propose tag synonyms or vote for them... I did come across a lot of duplicate tags ([htaccess](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/htaccess)/[.htaccess](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/.htaccess), [ce-1.9.2.2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ce-1.9.2.2)/[magento-1.9.2.2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magento-1.9.2.2)), overly specific tags or too generic tags. Therefor I do want to join this discussion. And by "a new *section* next to voting, answering and closing" you probably mean to create a *Tag* channel on Slack?

Let's also try to set a standard for tag wiki's and try to provide one for all popular tags.

Comment: Yes, I thought of a channel on Slack. A standard for tag wikis is a good idea, too

Comment: Slack Channel created: https://magestackday.slack.com/messages/tags/