# Register now for MageStackDay IV on January 15th & 16th 2016

Tags: discussion, feature-request

MageStackDay is back!
As announced here earlier, MageStackDay #4  is going to take place on the **15th & 16th of January 2016**!

**>> Please sign up here:** [MageStackday IV registration form](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/10Xq23K-Ev4vN2ykWXSeaPSvZbt8zq7nkzyefgA0Bw0o/viewform?c=0&w=1)

We'll be cleaning up magento.stackexchange.com which means:

- answer questions
- vote for answers and questions
- close questions
- clean up tags (as suggested [here](https://magento.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/792/request-for-magestackday-iv-tag-cleanup))

The goal will be to get the answered questions rate up by at least a few percent and get more users active on this platform.

In between we'll have some fun in the [MageStackday-Slack team](http://magestackday.slack.com). Please ping us if you're not already member of this group and you want to join.

Looking forward to your participation!

Comment: just check  in  magestackday.slack.com.Testing testing.... any one have alive at there

Answer (score 3):

Also, we are giving away MageStackDay stickers at the following events

**Netherlands**

- Dutchento NY Drink
- Magento 2 Hackathon 23 January

**Italy**

- MageTitansIt

**Germany**

- Mage Unconference

... more to follow

Comment: Hee Sander, aren't all those events past MSD? So these stickers are there as souvenirs, to be remembered of the good times at MSD 2016 :P

Comment: Jup, like war trophies :P

Comment: Want to have one on my laptop just like Fabian https://twitter.com/fschmengler/status/688090917534863360

Comment: You'll get one Wednesday ;)